# Populating a list using an SQLite database

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite, listactivity

I am pretty new in android application development and I am trying to get on of the rows from a SQLite db to show up as a Listactivity, but this is not working and the program terminates unexpectedly. Here is the code:

```
package ankur.test.app;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class testMenu extends ListActivity{

    HotOrNot Infor = new HotOrNot(this);
    {
        Infor.open();
    }
    String[] result = Infor.getList();
    {
        Infor.close();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle ankurtestlist) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(ankurtestlist);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(testMenu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, result));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Object cheese = result[position];
    /*  try{
        Class ourClass = Class.forName("ankur.test.app."+ cheese);
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(testMenu.this, ourClass);
        startActivity(ourIntent);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
    }
}
```

and this is the method in another class:

```
public String[] getList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HOTNESS};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        ArrayList name = new ArrayList(); 
        int i = 0;

        int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            name.add(c.getString(iName));
            i++;
        }

        String[] result = (String[]) name.toArray();
        return result;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are having a context problem, just put your initialize your new `Infor  = HotOrNot(this);` inside the `onCreate()` and edit your code as,

```
String[] result;
HotOrNot Infor;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle ankurtestlist) {
        super.onCreate(ankurtestlist);\

        Infor = new HotOrNot(this);
        Infor.open();
        result = Infor.getList();
        Infor.close();
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(testMenu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, result));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply but when i remove the initializing statements from the original place and put it inside onCreate(), the onListItemClick() is not able to read it and thus gives an error. If i leave the initialization statements at both the original and in onCreate(), i get the same error.

Comment: Well just declare them as global and then initialize in `onCreate()`, I edited my answer.